# How to Round a Time in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, rounding

I'me looking for a function that would receive a time and would round it to the next/previous hour / half-hour / quarter / minute.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try this function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RoundTime] (@Time datetime, @RoundTo float)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @RoundedTime smalldatetime
   DECLARE @Multiplier float

   SET @Multiplier= 24.0/@RoundTo

   SET @RoundedTime= ROUND(CAST(CAST(CONVERT(varchar,@Time,121) AS datetime) AS float) * @Multiplier,0)/@Multiplier

   RETURN @RoundedTime
END



select dbo.roundtime('13:15',0.5)
```

The 1st param is the time to be rounded and the 2nd will be base on your list (0.5-half hour, 1-one hour, ...)

Comment: If you use 121 in place of 113 it will get the datepart correct also

Comment: Worth nothing that increments must be specified as decimal notation of a fraction of an hour. So if you want it rounded to 5-minute intervals, then that is 1/12 of an hour, so @RoundTo would be .083.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. To avoid the hassle of calculating a float yourself, you can also call the function like this, to get a result rounded to 5 minutes: SELECT dbo.RoundTime('2016-11-28 10:57:50.000', CAST(5 AS float) / CAST(60 AS float)) where 5 is the number of minutes to round to and 60 is the total number of minutes in an hour (obviously).

Comment: Updating this to "SET @Multiplier= 1440.0 /@RoundTo" allows you to give the minutes to round to in the @RoundTo parameter. Also consider replacing Round() with Ceiling() if you want the nearest rounded time *after* your input time

Answer (score 6):

Very nice thanks. I used it in-line to round to 15 minutes

```
convert(smalldatetime,ROUND(cast(TDatalog.Time as float) * (24/.25),0)/(24/.25)) AS RoundedTime
```