# Issues with T-SQL function to round time to earliest hour

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime

I need to write a function that rounds time in one column to start at its original hour (ex: 23:33:00.0000000 would be 23:00) and time in another column to round up to the next hour (ex: 23:33:00.0000000 would be 24:00) and then insert these new values into new columns.  I found this function on Stack Overflow at [How to Round a Time in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/249794/61754), but I can't get the function to run.  I keep getting this error message: 'Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure RoundTime, Line 11 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.'

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RoundTime] (@Time datetime, @RoundTo float)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @RoundedTime smalldatetime
   DECLARE @Multiplier float
   SET @Multiplier= 24.0/@RoundTo
   SET @RoundedTime= ROUND(CAST(CAST(CONVERT(varchar,@Time,121) AS datetime) AS float) * @Multiplier,0)/@Multiplier
   RETURN @RoundedTime
END
SELECT [dbo].[RoundTime] ('23:33',0.0)
```

I've also tried running it with SELECT dbo.roundtime('23:33',0.0) and still no joy.

So I was hoping to try and figure out how to round the time via getting this function to run, but I can't even run it.  And I don't know the best way to approach getting the hour to round back to its earliest point anyway.  Would I just need to extract the hour from the timestamp and then do my insertion of that hour into its new column?  Or is there a way to convert it on the fly and then insert it into a new column?  I'm using Sql Server 2008.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function has to exist before you can reference it. Add a GO after the function declaration to separate the creation from the usage.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RoundTime] (@Time datetime, @RoundTo float)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @RoundedTime smalldatetime
   DECLARE @Multiplier float
   SET @Multiplier= 24.0/@RoundTo
   SET @RoundedTime= ROUND(CAST(CAST(CONVERT(varchar,@Time,121) AS datetime) AS float) * @Multiplier,0)/@Multiplier
   RETURN @RoundedTime
END
GO

SELECT [dbo].[RoundTime] ('23:33',0.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

`SET @Multiplier= 24.0/@RoundTo` and you're passing `0.0` in for the value of `@RoundTo`  What happens if you pass in `1.0`?

Now that you have it running, drop the function and replace it with this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RoundTime] 
(
    @Time datetime, 
    @RoundTo float
) 
RETURNS datetime 
AS 
BEGIN    
    DECLARE @RoundedTime datetime    
    DECLARE @Multiplier float    
    SET @Multiplier= 24.0/@RoundTo    
    SET @RoundedTime= FLOOR(CAST(CAST(CONVERT(varchar,@Time,121) AS datetime) AS float) * @Multiplier)/@Multiplier    
    RETURN @RoundedTime 
END
```

Switching from smalldatetime to datetime for the @RoundedTime variable stopped it throwing away the time.  Changing `Round` to `Floor` gets you the first number you're looking for, and you know you always add an hour to it.  You may want to rename the function to match what it's now doing...

Oh, and the second parameter should be 1.0 (`SELECT [dbo].[RoundTime] ('23:33:45',1.0)`)

Comment: Now that I have the function running (thanks to Joe) , it returns 1900-01-02 00:00:00.000 when I pass in a 1.0.  Which is not what I was hoping for.

Comment: @Lynn - Mark Joe's answer as correct and open a new question with a new problem, stating the behaviour you desire.

Comment: I did mark it as correct and thanks to Joe for getting me going.  it took me a few more minutes and I was able to answer the other part of my question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would get the syntax error, but when I run that, I get a divide by zero error.  I don't think the function was meant to be ran with 0 in the second parameter.  But that leaves you unable to round down I think.  In that case, you could just use 1 for the second parameter which rounds up to the next hour, then do a dateadd -1 hour to go back. (Or enhance the function).

Comment: Here's what I discovered.  I can extract the hour value and either keep it or add one to it (if it's in the EndTime column):  

SELECT (DATEPART(HOUR, [StartTime]) / 1) ,[EndTime]
  FROM [DesignTest].[dbo].[Site_Availability_Stg]
  ORDER BY OutageDate ASC   

This will get me to where I'm going for now.  Thanks for you input.  Very appreciated.