# How to write a query to get number of queries per minute in a database which is fed with the log files 

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

The Table(Log Analyzer) structure is :

[image: Table of Log]

I want to draw a line graph displaying the number of requests per minute. I want to     write a query which displays two columns with the following information:

1. Date:Hour:Minute
2. Number of Requests

I have tried to write a sample query displaying requests per hour:

```
SELECT ( Str(Datepart(HOUR, TimeLog)) + '.00' ) AS 'From (hours)',
       ( Str(CASE
               WHEN Datepart(HOUR, TimeLog) + 1 = 24 THEN 00
               ELSE Datepart(HOUR, TimeLog) + 1
             END) + '.00' )AS 'To (hours)',
       Count(DISTINCT Request) AS 'Number Of Queries '
FROM   LogData
GROUP  BY Datepart(HOUR, TimeLog);
```

The problem with this is when I use `MINUTE` instead of `HOUR` it combines the minutes of
all hours and days, so it just displays 60 rows. I want all the rows to be separate according to the day and hour. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select  convert(nvarchar(16), TimeLog, 120) requestTime,
        count(*)
from    LogData
group by convert(nvarchar(16), TimeLog, 120)`
```

Comment: HI ,I want to create a query similar to above but it should display  number of sessions in every 15 minutes . and the group by clause will remain the same (ie. every minute)
For example : at 10:00:00 it should represent number of sessions (sessionID) in last 15 minutes to 10:00:00 ie: 9:45:00 to 10:00:00 and so on ...

Comment: @RishiRanka http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249794/how-to-round-a-time-in-t-sql

Comment: This is something different . I want my output to be --------->
                   
Time:2012-06-06 10:00:00    , No Of Sessions: 123(Random) ;
Time:2012-06-06 10:00:01    , No Of Sessions: 212(Random)

Where 123 should be the number of sessions in the last 15 mins to 10:00  ie from 09:45 to 10:00
and 212 should be the number of sessions in the last 15 mins to 10:01  ie from 09:46 to 10:01