# Get the ten minute intervals from a range of datetimes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a datetime column with range of Datetime values. I want to create another column with all this datetime values but to round down to ten minute period.

So, something like this:

```
datetimesent              |     ten_minute_column

2012-06-11 18:27:58.000   |     2012-06-11 18:20:00.000
2012-06-15 15:19:08.000   |     2012-06-15 15:10:00.000
...                       |
```

The farthest I have got is playing around with is getting it in minute bucket slots.
I got this by doing:

```
SELECT DatetimeSent,
    DATEADD(Minute, DATEDIFF(Minute, 0, DatetimeSent), 0) AS Minute_bucket
FROM allrequests
```

But I need ten minute bucket slots.

Comment: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249794/how-to-round-a-time-in-t-sql. This post has many examples as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/830792/t-sql-round-to-nearest-15-minute-interval

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
select dateadd(minute, datepart(minute, datetimesent) / 10 * 10, 
dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0,datetimesent), 0)) ten_minute_column
from 
(select cast('2012-06-11 18:27:58.000' as datetime) datetimesent
union all
 select cast('2012-06-15 15:19:08.000' as datetime)) a
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using lots of functions:

```
WITH D AS
(   SELECT  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP [DateField]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  DATEADD(MINUTE, 5, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
)
SELECT  DATEADD(MINUTE, (10 * FLOOR(DATEPART(MINUTE, DateField) / 10.0)) - DATEPART(MINUTE, DateField), DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, DateField), 0)) AS RoundedDate
FROM    D
```

The gist of this is stripping out the number of minutes past a 10 minute interval and deducting this from the actual number of minutes (with seconds removed).

This can be tidied up a bit by moving some of the functions to a join. However, I don't think this offers any performance gain (not done any testing at all)

```
;WITH T AS
(   SELECT  Number,
            (10 * FLOOR(Number / 10.0)) - Number [RoundedDifference]
    FROM    (   SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Object_ID) - 1 [Number]
                FROM    sys.All_Objects
            ) n
    WHERE   Number < 60
), D AS
(   SELECT  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP [DateField]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  DATEADD(MINUTE, 5, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
)
SELECT  DateField,
        DATEADD(MINUTE, RoundedDifference, DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, DateField), 0)) [RoundedDate]
FROM    D
        INNER JOIN T
            ON DATEPART(MINUTE, DateField) = Number
```

Comment: It doesn't appear as clean as the accepted answer, but this is DEFINITELY the correct answer to this question!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are never milliseconds, you can strip minutes and seconds this way, and group on the result:

```
SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, -(CONVERT(INT, RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(2),
  DATEPART(MINUTE, GETDATE())),1))*60)-(DATEPART(SECOND,GETDATE())), GETDATE());
```

Here is a query that gets the right number of time slots based on the min and max dates from the table (or a subset of the table):

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(datetimesent DATETIME);
INSERT @x SELECT '2012-06-11 18:27:58.000'
UNION ALL SELECT '2012-06-15 15:19:08.000';

DECLARE @start SMALLDATETIME, @end SMALLDATETIME, @i INT;

SELECT @start = CONVERT(DATE, MIN(datetimesent)), @end = CONVERT(DATE,
MAX(datetimesent))
FROM @x
-- WHERE ...;

SELECT @i = DATEDIFF(DAY, @start, @end) * 144;

;WITH slots(ten_minute_column) AS
(
   SELECT TOP (@i * 144) DATEADD(MINUTE, 10 * (ROW_NUMBER() OVER
   (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])-1), @start)
   FROM sys.all_columns AS s1
   -- you may need to cross join to another table if this doesn't
   -- provide enough rows. Depends on overall datediff...
)
SELECT x.datetimesent, slots.ten_minute_column
 FROM @x AS x
 INNER JOIN slots
 ON x.datetimesent >= slots.ten_minute_column
 AND x.datetimesent < DATEADD(MINUTE, 10, slots.ten_minute_column)
 -- WHERE ...;
```

Results:

```
datetimesent              ten_minute_column
-----------------------   -------------------
2012-06-11 18:27:58.000   2012-06-11 18:20:00
2012-06-15 15:19:08.000   2012-06-15 15:10:00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  DatetimeSent,
        Dateadd(ms, -Datepart(ms, Dateadd(minute, Datediff(minute, 0, 
                                                    Dateadd(minute, 
                                                    -Datepart(minute, 
                                                     datetimesent) 
                                                    %10, 
                                                    datetimesent)), 0 
                                                ) 
                ), Dateadd(minute, Datediff(minute, 0, Dateadd(minute, 
                                                       - 
                                   Datepart( 
                                   minute, 
                                                   datetimesent 
                                   )% 
                                   10, 
                                     datetimesent 
                                                   )), 0)) AS Minute_bucket
FROM   allrequests
```