# Sorting result set according to variable in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a *resultset* with columns:

```
interval_start(timestamp) , camp  , queue , other columns
2012-09-10 11:10            c1      q1
2012-09-10 11:20            c1      q2
```

**interval_start** is having values in 10 minutes interval like :

```
2012-09-10 11:10,

2012-09-10 11:20,

2012-09-10 11:30 ....
```

using *Joda Time* library and **interval_start** field, I have created a variable to create string such that if minutes of **interval_start** lie between 00-30, 30 is set in minutes else 00 is set in minutes.

I want to group the data as :

```
camp as group1
variable created as group2
queue as group3
```

and done some aggregations

But in my report result, I am getting same queue many time in same interval.
I have used `order by camp, interval_start, queue` but the problem is still exists.

Attaching screenshot for your reference:

[image]

Is there any way to sort the *resultset* according to created variable?

Answer (score 0):

Best guess would be an issue with your actual SQL Query. You say the same queue is being repeated, but from looking at your image it is not actually be repeated it is a different row.

Your query is going to be tough to pull off, as you are really wanting to your query to have an order by of `order by camp, (rounded)interval_start, queue`. Without that it is ordering by the `camp` column, and then the non-rounded version of `interval_start` and then `camp`. When means that the data is not in the correct order for Jasper Reports to group them the way you want. And then the real kicker is Jasper Reports does not have the functionality to sort the data once it gets it. It is up to the developer to supply that.

So you have a couple options:

1. Update your SQL Query to do the rounding of your time. Depending on your database this is done in different ways, but will likely required some type of stored procedure or function to handle it (see this [TSQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/249828/3340) for example).
2. instead of having the sql query in the report, move it outside the report, and process the data, doing the rounding and sorting on the java side. Then pass it is as a the `REPORT_DATASOURCE` parameter.
3. Add a column to your table to store the rounded time. You may be able to create a trigger to handle this all in the database, with out having to change any of your other code in your application.

Honestly both these options are not ideal, and I hope someone comes along and provides an answer that proves me wrong. But I do not think there is currently a better way.