# Split query results into 15 minute intervals

Tags: group-by, sql-server-2012

Hope you can help me with this one...  I'm needing to do some analysis on some data stored in a SQL Server 2012 database.

I've currently got the query splitting the results into 1 hour chunks, but I also need queries to split the results into 15 minute and 30 minute chucks and I've got no clue how to do it.  I've had a look online, but what I was finding didn't make too much sense.

Below is the code I'm using for the hourly split

```
SELECT Name, Description, CONVERT(varchar(14), RecordedDateTime, 113) + ':00:00' AS RecordedDateHour,
  COUNT(Id) AS TotalRecordings, MIN(RecordedDateTime) AS MinRecordedDateTime,
  MAX(RecordedDateTime) AS MaxRecordedDateTime,
  COUNT(DISTINCT Id) AS TotalDistinctIds
FROM MainTable
WHERE RecordedDateTime >='21 May 2013' AND RecordedDateTime < '23 May 2013'
GROUP BY Name, Description, CONVERT(varchar(14), RecordedDateTime, 113) + ':00:00'
ORDER BY Name, Description, CONVERT(varchar(14), RecordedDateTime, 113) + ':00:00'
```

Any help you could give would be great.

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 0):

Not that you asked, but it's *highly* problematic that you're comparing date ranges in a char-type value containing things like "21 May 2013". For example, what about "22 May 2012"?

As a general approach, if you want to collect data in terms of time brackets, check out this StackOverflow question and answer: [How to Round a Time in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249794/how-to-round-a-time-in-t-sql)

Then `GROUP BY` the rounded time value.