# Rounding Datetime to nearest 15 minutes in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, rounding

I have a problem in SQL Server with rounding `datetime`. I got `datetime` in column `rec_datetime`, but I want to round this `datetime` in a new column `r_datetime`, which has to be rounded to nearest 15 min, for the whole column `rec_datetime`.

**Example:**

- `[2015-11-24 19:06:00.000]` - expected result ->  `[2015-11-24 19:00:00.000]`
- `[2015-11-24 19:09:00.000]` - expected result ->  `[2015-11-24 19:15:00.000]`

Is it possible to round it via select for whole column? Something like :

```
select round(rec_datetime.......
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Round a Time in T-SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249794/how-to-round-a-time-in-t-sql)

Answer (score 21):

**Round-down, round-nearest & round-up to nearest 15mins**

```
DATEADD( minute, ( DATEDIFF( minute, 0,                                   dateTimeX   ) / 15 ) * 15, 0 ) AS dateTimeRoundDown
DATEADD( minute, ( DATEDIFF( minute, 0, DATEADD( second, ( 15 * 60 ) / 2, dateTimeX ) ) / 15 ) * 15, 0 ) AS dateTimeRoundNearest
DATEADD( minute, ( DATEDIFF( minute, 0, DATEADD( minute,   15           , dateTimeX ) ) / 15 ) * 15, 0 ) AS dateTimeRoundUp
```

**Round Down**

```
DATEADD( minute, ( DATEDIFF( minute, 0, dateTimeX ) / 15 ) * 15, 0 ) AS dateTimeRoundDown
```

Get the offset in minutes (number of minutes since the base-date):

```
DATEDIFF( minute, 0, dateTimeX )
```

Round-down to 15 minute block by integer dividing:

```
DATEDIFF( minute, 0, dateTimeX ) / 15 ) * 15
```

Add the base-date back in minutes:

```
DATEADD( minute, ( DATEDIFF( minute, 0, dateTimeX ) / 15 ) * 15, 0 )
```

**Round Nearest**

```
DATEADD( minute, ( DATEDIFF( minute, 0, DATEADD( second, ( 15 * 60 ) / 2, dateTimeX ) ) / 15 ) * 15, 0 ) AS dateTimeRoundNear
```

15 / 2 minutes is added to the offset.

Needs to be in seconds due to the integer division.

**Round Up**

```
DATEADD( minute, ( DATEDIFF( minute, 0, DATEADD( minute, 15, dateTimeX ) ) / 15 ) * 15, 0 ) AS dateTimeRoundUp
```

15 minutes is added to the offset

**Base Date**

I generally use a base date of 0 which is the SQL Server 'epoch'

```
SELECT DATEADD( minute, 0, 0 ) -- '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
```

Because DATEADD() & DATEDIFF() use the SQL Server data type of INT (32 bits) for the parameters, for dates in the very far future, this may cause an overflow.

Using another fixed date, eg '2010-01-01', will avoid the overflow.

The chosen base-date must have a time part of 00:00:00

Using a base-date and integer division, no casting & no floating point operations are required.

**Unit Testing**

```
DECLARE @start DATETIME  = '2017-04-20 21:00:00'
DECLARE @end   DATETIME  = '2017-04-20 22:00:00'

;WITH CTE_dateTimes AS
(
    SELECT @start AS dateTimeX
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD( minute, 1, dateTimeX )
    FROM CTE_dateTimes
    WHERE DATEADD( minute, 1, dateTimeX ) <= @end
)
SELECT dateTimeX,
   DATEADD( minute, ( DATEDIFF( minute, 0,                                   dateTimeX   ) / 15 ) * 15, 0 ) AS dateTimeRoundDown,
   DATEADD( minute, ( DATEDIFF( minute, 0, DATEADD( second, ( 15 * 60 ) / 2, dateTimeX ) ) / 15 ) * 15, 0 ) AS dateTimeRoundNearest,
   DATEADD( minute, ( DATEDIFF( minute, 0, DATEADD( minute,   15           , dateTimeX ) ) / 15 ) * 15, 0 ) AS dateTimeRoundUp

FROM CTE_dateTimes
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT
  dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, '1999-12-31 23:52:30', col) / 15*15, '2000-01-01')
FROM (values('2015-11-24 19:06:00.000'),('2015-11-24 19:09:00.000')) x(col)
```

Result:

```
2015-11-24 19:00:00.000
2015-11-24 19:15:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to round the minute to nearest 15

try query like this:

```
SELECT

 original_datetime

 --: this will give you the minute part
 , datepart(minute, original_datetime) AS minuteFromDate

 --: now get the nearest minute part to 15min, round it nearest to 15
 , round(datepart(minute, original_datetime)  * 1.0 / 15 , 0) * 15.0 AS roundedToNearest15

 -- now remove the minute from original datetime, & add the rounded minute to the resultant datetime value
 -- this will give you expected result
 , dateadd(minute 
             , (round(datepart(minute, original_datetime) * 1.0 / 15 , 0) * 15.0)
             , dateadd(minute, -datepart(minute, original_datetime), original_datetime)
           ) as rec_datetime

FROM (values('2015-11-24 19:06:00.000')
           ,('2015-11-24 19:09:00.000')
         ,('2015-11-24 19:56:00.000')
         ,('2015-11-24 19:48:00.000')
     ) x(original_datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nearest 15 minutes:

```
SELECT DateTimeX =  GETDATE(), RoundedDateTimeX = CAST(CAST(CAST(GETDATE() as float) * (24 * 60/15) + 0.5 as bigint) / (24.0 * 60/15) as datetime)
```

Nearest 15 minutes rounded up:

```
SELECT DateTimeX =  GETDATE(), RoundedDateTimeX = CAST(CAST(CAST(GETDATE() as float) * (24 * 60/15) + 1 as bigint) / (24.0 * 60/15) as datetime)
```

Note:  The decimal 24.0 in devisor changes type back to float.