# Round time(7) column values no nearest 15 minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have columns of type time(7)[nulls allowed], some of the values need to be to be adjusted to the nearest 15 minute mark and the seconds set to zero.

Example:

```
09:00:40.0000000 -> 09:00:00.0000000
12:50:00.0000000 -> 12:45:00.0000000
12:59:37.0000000 -> 13:00:00.0000000
```

Comment: You have only time part in your value? or date part also there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounding Datetime to nearest 15 minutes in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33938120/rounding-datetime-to-nearest-15-minutes-in-sql-server)

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830792/t-sql-round-to-nearest-15-minute-interval

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
SELECT 
CAST
(
    DATEADD(MINUTE, ROUND(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0,
    CAST('2015-11-24  ' -- Add any day for converting to DateTime
    +LEFT('09:00:40.0000000',LEN('09:00:40.0000000') - 4) -- Removing last four zero from your data to convert to date time
    AS DATETIME)) / 15.0, 0) * 15, 0) 
    AS TIME
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [`timefromparts()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/timefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments):

```
select timefromparts(datepart(hour, timecol),
                     (datepart(minute, timecol) / 15) * 15,
                     0, 0, 6)
```

The above truncates the value.  Rounding the value is a little tricker.  I would recommend:

```
select timefromparts(datepart(hour, dateadd(second, 7 * 60 + 30, timecol)),
                     (datepart(minute, dateadd(second, 7 * 60 + 30, timecol)) / 15) * 15,
                     0, 0, 6)
```

That is, add 7.5 minutes and truncate.