# Substract time based on 2 parameters

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server

Table **Persona**

```
ID   Name   Date        Timer    InOrOut
----------------------------------------
1    Seth   2020-05-26  07:00   I
2    Seth   2020-05-26  17:00   O
3    Maria  2020-05-25  06:59   I
4    Maria  2020-05-25  07:00   I
5    Maria  2020-05-25  16:49   O
6    Maria  2020-05-25  17:01   O
```

This is my query

```
SELECT Name As Name, Date AS Data,
case when InOrOut = 'I' then CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), CAST(Timer AS TIME), 108) end as In, 
case when InOrOut= 'U' then CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), CAST(Timer AS TIME), 108) end as Out
FROM Persona 
GROUP BY Date, Name, InOrOut, Timer ORDER BY Date DESC
```

And this is the output of the above query

```
Name   Date          In      Out
----------------------------------------
Seth   2020-05-26    07:00   NULL
Seth   2020-05-26    NULL    17:00
Maria  2020-05-25    06:59   NULL
Maria  2020-05-25    07:00   NULL
Maria  2020-05-25    NULL    16:49
Maria  2020-05-25    NULL    17:01
```

What I want to ask:

1. Is there a way to add another column named **TotalHours** where I substract **Out - In**? So like in **Seth** example would be **17:00 - 07:00** giving the result **10**?

Optional (I don't really care about the **2** point, but if someone could give a complete example that would be more than great)

2. Is there a way to display only one value for **Persona**? So like in the example **Maria In 6:59** (taking the lowest value) and **Maria Out 17:01** (taking the highest value) per day?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: group by persona.id and day to get it per person and day. then select datediff(hour,min(in),max(out)) to get the difference between the first in and last out in hours. You may need to deal with the null-values and duplicates per day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible statement, which returns the expected results:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Persona (
   ID int,
   Name varchar(50),
   [Date] date,
   Timer time,
   InOrOut varchar(1)
)
INSERT INTO Persona (ID, Name, [Date], Timer, InOrOut)
VALUES
   (1, 'Seth',  '20200526', '07:00', 'I'),
   (2, 'Seth',  '20200526', '17:00', 'O'),
   (3, 'Maria', '20200525', '06:59', 'I'),
   (4, 'Maria', '20200525', '07:00', 'I'),
   (5, 'Maria', '20200525', '16:49', 'O'),
   (6, 'Maria', '20200525', '17:01', 'O')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
   Name As Name, 
   Date AS Data,
   MIN(case when InOrOut = 'I' then CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Timer, 108) end) AS [In], 
   MAX(case when InOrOut = 'O' then CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Timer, 108) end) AS [Out],
   DATEDIFF(hour,
      MIN(case when InOrOut = 'I' then Timer end),
      MAX(case when InOrOut = 'O' then Timer end) 
   ) AS TotalHours
FROM Persona 
GROUP BY [Date], Name
ORDER BY [Date] DESC
```

Result:

```
Name    Data        In      Out     TotalHours
Seth    2020-05-26  07:00   17:00   10
Maria   2020-05-25  06:59   17:01   11
```

Comment: I have tried to make it out by following your example but it gives me error at the end. <br/>
**The column InOrOut is not valid in the selection because it is not included in an aggregation function or in the GROUP BY clause.** <br/>
**The column Timer is not valid in the selection because it is not included in an aggregation function or in the GROUP BY clause.**

Comment: @ChangeWorld The statement from the answer executes correctly. What is your current attempt? You do not need to use `InOrOut` in the `GROUP BY` clause. Thanks.

Comment: I'm really sorry, my bad, I written it incorrectly. Really appreciate your help, wish you the best. Regards

Comment: Sir, sorry to disturb you one more time, but I would like to ask you. If I want to update this question with some other details, what should I do? Ask another question?

Comment: @ChangeWorld, probably asking a new question should be your first option, but it depends on the details. Please, post these details as a comment here. Thanks.

Comment: I would like to reproduce your example because it really works for me and I would like to add some math if possible.
1)  When **InOurOut** is **I** and time is `06:02` or until `06:29` then it should calculate as `06:30` else if time is `06:31` or until `06:59` then it should calculate as `07:00`
2)  When **InOurOut** is **O** and time is `06:02` or until `06:29` then it should calculate as `06:00` else if time is `06:31` or until `06:59` then it should calculate as `06:30`. 
This is all about calculation, so all this would happen in the column `TotalHours`

Comment: This is a hard one I know.

Comment: @ChangeWorld One similar question with answers is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33938120/rounding-datetime-to-nearest-15-minutes-in-sql-server).

Comment: That's way too hard for me to understand. I'm going to try to make it work with a datatable. Thank you for the suggestion, if I can't do nothing probably tomorrow I'm going to ask another question similar to the one you linked me. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

This statement will give the same results as well...

```sql
WITH cte_DistinctNameDate AS
(
    SELECT      DISTINCT [Name], [Date]
    FROM        Persona
)
SELECT      d.[Name]
            , d.[Date]
            , CONVERT ( VARCHAR(5), MIN ( p.[Timer] ), 108 ) AS [In]
            , CONVERT ( VARCHAR(5), MAX ( p.[Timer] ), 108 ) AS [Out]
            , CAST ( DATEDIFF ( MI, MIN ( p.[Timer] ), MAX ( p.[Timer] ) ) / 60.0 AS DECIMAL (4,2) ) AS [TotalHours]
FROM        cte_DistinctNameDate AS d
INNER JOIN  Persona AS p
    ON      d.[Name] = p.[Name]
    AND     d.[Date] = p.[Date]
GROUP BY    d.[Name], d.[Date]
ORDER BY    d.[Date] DESC ;
```

But I think @Zhorov's is more efficient.

Or to refine it even further...

```sql
SELECT      [Name] AS [Name]
            , [Date] AS [Data]
            , CONVERT ( VARCHAR(5), MIN ( [Timer] ), 108 ) AS [In]
            , CONVERT ( VARCHAR(5), MAX ( [Timer] ), 108 ) AS [Out]
            , CAST ( DATEDIFF ( MI, MIN ( [Timer] ), MAX ( [Timer] ) ) / 60.0 AS DECIMAL (4,2) ) AS [TotalHours]
FROM        Persona
GROUP BY    [Name], [Date]
ORDER BY    [Date] DESC ;
```