# Counting Columns with conditions, assigning values based on count

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with call logs. I need to assign time slots for next call based on which time slot the phone number was reachable in.

The relevant columns of the table are:

Phone Number | CallTimeStamp

CallTimeStamp is a datetime object.

I need to calculate the following:

- **Time Slot**: From the TimeStamp, I need to calculate the count for each time slot (eg. 0800-1000, 1001-1200, etc.) for each phone number. Now, if the count is greater than 'n' for a particular time slot, then I need to assign that time slot to that number. Otherwise, I select a default time slot.
- **Weekday Slot**: Same as above, but with weekdays.
- **Priority**: Basically a count of how many times a number was reached

Here's I have gone about solving these issues:

#### Priority

To calculate the number of times a phone number is called is straight forward. If a number exists in the call log, I know that it was called. In that case, the following query will give me the call count for each number.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(PhoneNumber), COUNT(PhoneNumber) FROM tblCallLog
GROUP BY PhoneNumber
```

However, my problem is that I need to change the values in the field Count(PhoneNumber) based on the value in that column itself. How do I go about achieving this? (eg. If Count(PhoneNumber) gives me a value > 20, I need to change it to 5).

#### Time Slot / Weekday

This is where I'm completely stumped and am looking for the "database" way of doing things.

Unfortunately, I can't get out of my iterative process of thinking. For example, if I was aggregating for a certain phone number (say '123456') and in a certain time slot (say between 0800-1000 hrs), I can write a query like this:

```
DECLARE @T1Start time = '08:00:00.0000'
DECLARE @T2End time = '10:00:00.0000'

SELECT COUNT(CallTimeStamp) FROM tblCallLog 
WHERE PhoneNumber = '123456' AND FORMAT(CallTimeStamp, 'hh:mm:ss') >= @T1Start AND FORMAT(CallTimeStamp, 'hh:mm:ss') < @T2End
```

Now, I could go through each and every Distinct Phone Number in the table, count the values for each time slot and then assign a slot value for the phone number. However, there has to be a way that does not involve me iterating through a database.

So, I am looking for suggestions on how to solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DATEPART Function to get week day slot. 
To calculate time slot you can try dividing number of minutes from beginning of day and dividing it by size of the time slot. It would return you slot number. You can use either CASE statement to translate it to proper string or look table where you can store slot descriptions.

```sql
SELECT 
    PhoneNumber
    , DATEPART(WEEKDAY, l.CallTimeStamp) AS DayOfWeekSlot
    , DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CONVERT(DATE, l.CallTimeStamp), l.CallTimeStamp) / 120 AS TwoHourSlot /*You can change number of minutes to get different slot size*/
    , COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM tblCallLog l
GROUP BY PhoneNumber
    , DATEPART(WEEKDAY, l.CallTimeStamp) 
    , DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CONVERT(DATE, l.CallTimeStamp), l.CallTimeStamp) / 120
```

Comment: Thanks, I adapted tblCallLog to store DayOfWeekSlot and TwoHourSlot along with the CallTimeStamp (thanks to your query), Since these values are constantly needed, it made sense to store them as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this to return the phone number, the day of the week and a 2 hour slot. If the volume of calls is greater than 20 the value is set to 5 (not sure why to 5?). The code for the 2 hour section is adapted from this question [How to Round a Time in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249794/how-to-round-a-time-in-t-sql) where the value 2 in (24/2) is the number of hours in your time period.

```
SELECT  
      PhoneNumber
    , DATENAME(weekday,CallTimeStamp) as [day]
    , CONVERT(smalldatetime,ROUND(CAST(CallTimeStamp as float) * (24/2),0)/(24/2)) AS RoundedTime
    , CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 20 THEN 5 ELSE COUNT(*) END
FROM 
      tblCallLog
GROUP BY      
      PhoneNumber
    , DATENAME(weekday,dateadd(s,start_ts,'01/01/1970'))
```