# Group [time] by 5 sec intervals

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have data containing seconds [time] value. I'd like count my data based on how many records/second.

This works like this:

```
SELECT [Time], count(*) 

FROM [dbo].[Times]
GROUP BY
[Time] ORDER By [Time]
```

This gives me:

```
+----------+----+
| 00:00:00 | 4  |
+----------+----+
| 00:00:01 | 2  |
+----------+----+
| 00:00:02 | 1  |
+----------+----+
| 00:00:08 | 2  |
+----------+----+
...
```

I'd like to group and count them in 5 second intervals, so the result would look like:

```
+----------+----+
| 00:00:05 | 7  |   <--   # of records between 0:00:00 and 0:00:05
+----------+----+
| 00:00:10 | 2  |   <--   # of records between 0:00:05 and 0:00:10
+----------+----+
...
```

Any good way yo do this in MS SQL?

Comment: Look into an inline function to round time. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249794/how-to-round-a-time-in-t-sql

Comment: `SELECT Cast(Dateadd(SECOND, ( Datediff(SECOND, 0, [time]) / 5 + 1 ) * 5, 0) AS TIME) AS [secs],
       Count(*)       
FROM   [dbo].[Times] 
GROUP  BY Dateadd(SECOND, ( Datediff(SECOND, 0, [time]) / 5 + 1 ) * 5, 0); `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select cast(dateadd(second, (datediff(second, 0, [time]) / 5) * 5, 0) as time(0)) as [time],
       count(*)
from [dbo].[Times] t
group by dateadd(second, (datediff(second, 0, [time]) / 5) * 5, 0)
order by min([time]);
```

EDIT:

As pointed out in a comment, you can write:

```
select v.[Time], count(*)
from [dbo].[Times] t cross apply
     (values (cast(dateadd(second, (datediff(second, 0, [time]) / 5) * 5, 0) as time(0)) )
     ) as v([Time])
group by v.[Time]
order by v.[Time];
```

This puts the complicated calculation in only one place -- preventing the type of error that I made when editing the original answer.

Comment: The grouping part looks like it works well, but the display part is not how I expected. '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 : 7', '1900-01-06 00:00:00.000: 2'

Comment: Could you suggest some formatting on first column to look like: 00:00:05, 00:00:10 ... ?

Comment: You have misplaced the parameters in `DATEADD` function. Based on `DATEDIFF` result dates are generated. `DATEADD` function should be `dateadd(second, (datediff(second, 0, [time]) / 5 + 1 ) * 5,0 )`. I have added `/ 5 +1` to start the result with `00:00:05`

Comment: @DDan . . . You can cast to a `time`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - There wont be any `seconds` in your current approach. If you `CAST` it to `time` only one record you will get with total count. You need to change the `DATEADD` function. If you look closely I have swapped the position of parameters in `DATEADD` function in my first comment

Comment: This looks very good, I just edited the format to time(0) ti get up to seconds only (00:00:00, 00:00:05) ...

Comment: You could use `CROSS APPLY` to keep the `dateadd` code in one place for ease of maintenance.

Comment: @EdwardComeau . . . Great suggestion.  I edited the answer.